# Mootools: Traverse this.getParent() x amount of times to specific element

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools, traversal

The following markup is exaggerated to demonstrate the problem.

I'm trying to capture the main row of a clicked link...it just so happens that its buried deep within a bunch of other things.

```
<div class="mainRow">
...
</div>
<div class="mainRow">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>(x number of layers)
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="someLink">click me</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>(/x number of layers)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainRow">
...
</div>
```

In **mootools** *, you can manually get that parent element by saying `.getParent().getParent()...<xTimes>...getParent()` etc

Is there a way to arbitrarily *traverse up a chain of parents x number of times* so that it stops at `div.mainRow` ?

(**Edit**: lol... sorry everyone, i guess i wrote "jquery" in my question by mistake. i am asking about mootools.)

Comment: Actually in jQuery you'd do `$(this).closest('div.mainRow')` ...

Comment: I like it! how about mootools?

Comment: ... and it looks like MooTools has a `.getParents('div.mainRow')` ... I don't know MooTools so I'm not sure what you do to get to that function, but it's part of the `Element` class. It returns an array of nodes that match.

Comment: .getParents('div.mainRow') does the trick. if you wanna write it as a solution, i'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: surely `getParent()` - http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getParent - singular.

Comment: +1 Dimitar - `.getParent('div.mainRow'); ` should do the trick @Kristian

Comment: Well.... i want to be able to accept an answer. @DimitarChristoff, if you'd kindly write it as a solution, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parent traversal is simple in mootools.

in your case, the `getParent([optional selector])` method will try to match any parent node:
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getParent - so `.getParent("div.mainrow")` will return the first match or null - if none found.

you can also use a reverse combinator selector at times, though not on a click event, probably.

eg, `document.getElements("div.mainRow a.someLink ! div.mainRow")` will return only the div.mainRow elements that have a link with class "someLink" directly. in a way, like `.contains()` but you can return the parent of the a as well just by appending `! div`